Construct a torsion-free connection on Lie group
Let $G$ be a Lie group, and consider a connection for left-invariant vector fields on $G$ defined as
$$
\nabla_X(\sum_j\alpha_jZ_j):=\sum_j(X\alpha_j)Z_j
$$
where $\{Z_j\}$ is a global frame for left-invariant vector fields. I have computed, that the torsion and curvature of this connection is (let $X=\sum_i\alpha_iZ_i, \ Y=\sum_j\beta_jZ_j, \ Z=\sum_k\gamma_kZ_k$)
$$
T(X,Y)=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_i\beta_j[Z_i,Z_j] \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ R(X,Y)Z=0
$$
Now I want to construct a new connection $\tilde\nabla$ from $\nabla$, such that $\tilde\nabla$ is torsion-free. Is there any way to do it? I have no idea how to proceed.

I agree with the expression for torsion $T(X,Y)$ which makes me confident that I understood your connection. But for Riemann I get not zero: \begin{align}
R(X,Y)Z
&=\alpha^iZ_i(\beta^j)Z_j(\gamma^k)Z_k-\beta^jZ_j(\alpha^i)Z_i(\gamma^k)Z_k,.
\end{align} Can you check your calculations?

@KurtG. I have checked again, though I'm not sure if I'm right. But in my calculation, terms like $\alpha Z(\beta)Z(\gamma)Z$ (I omit the indicies) appears both in $\nabla_X\nabla_YZ$ and in $\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$, and they cancell each other. The same for $\beta \cdots$ Term.

I found a mistake in one of my calculations. Riemann is zero.

Just one thing: could there be a sign error in $T(X,Y),?$ Mine has a negative sign. This is compatible with Travis' answer.

@KurtG. I checked my answer again and I think there's no problem for $T(X,Y)$. Also, Travi's answer don't need a concrete form of torsion, I have checked that for an arbitrary connection $\nabla_XY$, the new connection $\nabla_XY-T(X,Y)/2$ is always torsion free.

I agree about $\nabla_XY-T(X,Y)/2$ being always torsion free. Nonetheless: your example is very interesting because it is concrete and I want to settle the dispute about that sign error. I'd be glad to hear from you.

Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1350167/155629

Hint For any affine connection $\nabla$ on a smooth manifold $M$ and any $(2, 1)$ tensor $A$, regarded as a bundle map $\bigotimes^2 TM \to TM$, we get another affine connection $\tilde\nabla$ defined by
$$\tilde\nabla_X Y := \nabla_X Y + A(X, Y)$$
(and all affine connections on $M$ arise this way). Now, compute the torsion $\tilde T$ of $\tilde\nabla$ in terms of the torsion $T$ of $\nabla$ and the modification $A$, and find conditions on $A$ such that $\tilde T = 0$.
Mechanically it might be easiest to work with the components of the tensors with respect to a local frame:
$$T_{ij}^k = \Gamma_{ij}^k - \Gamma_{ji}^k - \gamma_{ij}^k .$$
As usual, $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ are the connection coefficients (characterized by $\nabla_{Z_i} Z_j = \Gamma_{ij}^k Z_k$) and $\gamma_{ij}^k$ are the commutator coefficients (characterized by $[Z_i, Z_j] = \gamma_{ij}^k Z_k$). (This process works for any connection and any local frame, but for connections like the one in the problem statement, where all of the frame components are parallel, $\Gamma_{ij}^k = 0$ and so $T_{ij}^k = -\gamma_{ij}^k$.)

Substituting gives $$\tilde T_{ij}^k = T_{ij}^k + 2 A_{[ij]}^k,$$ where as usual brackets denote skewing over the enclosed indices, $2 A_{[ij]}^k = A_{ij}^k - A_{ji}^k$. So, the condition that $\tilde T = 0$ imposes exactly that $A_{[ij]}^k = -\frac12 T_{ij}^k$. There are infinitely many solutions $A$, but the simplest choice is to choose $A$ itself to be skew in its covariant indices, i.e., $$A = -\frac12 T .$$ Indeed, precisely when $A$ is skew in its covariant indices the geodesic equations for $\nabla, \tilde\nabla$ coincide, so $$\tilde\nabla_X Y := \nabla_X Y - \frac12 T(X, Y) = \frac12 (\nabla_X Y + \nabla_Y X + [X, Y]),$$ just as well specified by the connection coefficients $$\tilde\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac12(\Gamma_{ij}^k + \Gamma_{ji}^k + \gamma_{ij}^k) ,$$ is the unique torsion-free connection with the same geodesics as $\nabla$. In terms of a frame $(Z_i)$ whose components are all parallel with respect to $\nabla$, $\tilde\nabla$ is characterized by $\tilde \nabla_{Z_i} Z_j = \frac12 [Z_i, Z_j]$.


While I agree about $\tilde \nabla_X Y = \nabla_X Y - T(X,Y)/2$ being torsion free I am having some trouble to see this being equal to $\tilde \nabla_X Y = \nabla_X Y - \frac12 [X, Y],.$ See my answer. Specifically the last two bullet points.

I think there was a sign error, and the modification for the special case should be $\color{red}{+}\frac12[X,Y]$.

Thanks for coming back but I do not quite see that either. See (12), (13) in my updated answer.

I've removed the dubious statement and will take another look tomorrow. Thanks for bringing the issue to my attention.

The issue was that the formula $\frac12[X, Y]$ only applies when $X, Y$ are elements of the parallel frame. I've adjusted my answer.

Yes, exactly. I learned a lot today.

Cheers, and thanks again. You might be interested in my older answer that I linked inside the spoiler in the answer.


To settle the dispute about a potential sign error in $T(X,Y)\,:$

With $X=\alpha^iZ_i,Y=\beta^jZ_j\,,$ I get
\begin{align*}\tag1
\nabla_XY&=\alpha^i\nabla_{Z_i}Y=\alpha^iZ_i(\beta^j)Z_j\,,\\[2mm]
\nabla_YX&=\beta^j\nabla_{Z_j}X=\beta^jZ_j(\alpha^i)Z_i\,,\tag2\\[2mm]
[X,Y]&=(\alpha^iZ_i)\,(\beta^jZ_j)-(\beta^jZ_j)\,(\alpha^iZ_j)\tag3\\[2mm]
&=\alpha^i\beta^jZ_iZ_j-\beta^j\alpha^iZ_jZ_i+\alpha^iZ_i(\beta^j)\,Z_j-\beta^jZ_j(\alpha^i)\,Z_i\tag4\\[2mm]
&=\alpha^i\beta^j[Z_i,Z_j]+\alpha^iZ_i(\beta^j)\,Z_j-\beta^jZ_j(\alpha^i)\,Z_i\,,\tag5
\end{align*}
which gives
\begin{align*}\tag6
[X,Y]=\alpha^i\beta^j[Z_i,Z_j]+\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX\,
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align}\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}
T(X,Y)=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y]=\color{red}{-}\,\alpha^i\beta^j[Z_i,Z_j]\,.\quad}\tag7
\end{align}

The torsion free connection found by Travis Wilse is
$$\tag8
\tilde \nabla_X Y = \nabla_X Y - \frac12 T(X, Y)\,.
$$
Indeed:
\begin{align}\tag9
\tilde T(X,Y)&=\tilde \nabla_X Y-\tilde \nabla_Y X-[X,Y]\\[2mm]&=
\underbrace{\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y]}_{T(X,Y)}-\tfrac12 T(X,Y)+\tfrac12 T(Y,X)
=0\,.\tag{10}
\end{align}
Rather than
$$\tag{11}
\tilde\nabla_XY=\nabla_XY\pm \tfrac12[X,Y]
$$ I think we should get in OP's case

\begin{align*}\tag{12}
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}\tilde\nabla_XY=\tfrac12\nabla_XY+\tfrac12\nabla_YX+\tfrac12[X,Y]\quad}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}\tag{13}
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}\tilde\nabla_XY=\alpha^iZ_i(\beta^j)Z_j+\tfrac12\alpha^i\beta^j[Z_i,Z_j]\,.\quad}
\end{align*}
